# Problema con optimizacion cuadratica quadprog en Python

Tags: python, matlab

Tengo un código en Matlab que lleva a cabo una optimización mediante la función quadprog

```
deltaU = quadprog(H,f,M,gamma)
```

Esto es parte de un controlador MPC en el que H,f,M y gamma son matrices con las siguientes dimensiones:
H (30x30)
f (30x1)
M (180x30)
gamma (180x1)

En matlab el quadprog funciona bien y me devuelve un vector resultado, sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas al pasar el código a Python.

En python, estoy usando la función quadprog solver de qpsolvers:

```
import numpy as np
import qpsolvers
from qpsolvers import solve_qp
```

Las matrices que uso tienen las mismas dimensiones que en Matlab, sin embargo lo que me devuelve al función es un resultado del tipo NonType object.

```
sol_qp = solve_qp(H, f, M, gamma)
```

El solver funciona, ya que lo he probado con los ejemplos de su página web, por lo que no entiendo donde está el error. Las matrices están definidas en Numpy.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error, el solver no acepta las matrices unidimensionales con un formato (30x1) tienen que ser un array (30,).

Quizás no es la forma más efectiva, pero lo solucioné así:

```
f2 = f[:,0]
gamma2 = gamma[:,0]
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.